# como permitir acesso no arquivo .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, localhost

Meu ".htaccess" está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|

RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

ele se encontra no diretório principal, se eu apagar esse aquivo o site funciona em localhost, porém sem formatação e sem funcionalidades, com o `.htaccess` aparece a mensagem:

> **Erro do Servidor Interno**
>
> O servidor encontrou um erro interno ou errada e não pôde concluir sua
>   solicitação.
>
> Entre em contato com o administrador do servidor na admin @ localhost
>   para informá-los do tempo ocorreu esse erro, e as ações que você
>   executada imediatamente antes de este erro.
>
> Mais informações sobre este erro pode estar disponível no log de erro
>   do servidor.

alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: O que tinha no log do servidor referente ao erro?

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o mod_rewrite do apache está habilitado, você pode habilita-lo via terminal no linux:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

ou (no windows) via o arquivo httpd.conf do apache que contém os modulos, basta descomentar a linha com o módulo:

```
#LoadModulo rewrite_modulo modulos/mod_rewrite.so
```

Não esqueça de reiniciar o serviço do apache em seguida para que as alterações tenham efeito.